# Sonar: Connection between plugins (Findbugs, PMD,...), dashboard, and WS API

Tags: sonarqube

As a simple user of sonar results (dashboard and through the web service API) I would need to know which data shown on the dashboard and which metrics available on the API were created by which tool/plugin (Findbugs, PMD, the internal rule engine, etc.). 
Is there some list/documentation available? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point of your question, but here's what you have to know:

- SonarQube relies less and less on external tools like Checkstyle or PMD, and more and more on its own parsers and analysers to generate measures and issues
- Plugins that integrate third-party tools (Findbugs, PMD, Checkstyle, ...etc) usually only contribute rules that allow to generate issues. You can easily see which rules are contributed by those plugins by looking at their definition in the UI (the name of their repository contains the name of the tool)
- For unit test and coverage information, they are always retrieved from reports previously generated by testing tools like JUnit/TestNG for Java, PHPUnit for PHP, ...etc.

Comment: Thank you, I can e.g. find rules from Findbug in the nemo sonar instance. However, as far as I understood there are a lot of others involved, e.g. Jacoco or others for coverage, the SQUALE plugin etc. It would be helpful to know the source of measures, e.g. to better understand the definition of the measures available in the REST api. I couldn't find any possibility (for an user) to get this information, or any overview on measure sources in a (standard) sonar instance.